# rmarkdown - export table of contents

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an RMarkdown file used for creating a QC report on other sets of data, and the report is relatively long. My table of contents essentially contains the name of all the checks I run on the data, and I'd like to have the table of contents itself exported into a new document, for outside users to quickly see what checks are run.

Is there any way to export just the TOC to word/pdf/html, or otherwise 'roll up' and export the different sections of an RMarkdown file?

Comment: I am looking for something similar, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Perhaps you're after a "floating" TOC, like this?

````
---
title: "Title"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---


# Section 1

```{r}
stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(4, start_lipsum = TRUE)
```

# Section 2

```{r}
stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(4, start_lipsum = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear - I'd like just the TOC to be exported (in this case, the name of R analyses being run) to some external file. Do you know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

For a `html_document` output format, you can set the `body` [Pandoc variable](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#structural-variables) to a void string:

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: ['-V', 'body=""']
---
```

This solution will not work for a `pdf_document` or a `word_document`.